# How do I specify different color ranges for different levels?

Tags: r, lattice, na, levelplot

I am making a lattice `levelplot` from `x` and `y` factors that range from [0,1]:

```
      x     y     level                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
1 m3134 m3134 1.0000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
2 m3134 m416B 0.4189057                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
3 m416B m3134 0.2696508                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
4 m3134  mA20 0.3322170                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
5  mA20 m3134 0.2454191                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
6 m3134    mB 0.3176792
...
```

Here is the R script that I use to make the figure from this data:

```
#!/foo/bar/bin/Rscript --vanilla                                                                                                                                                                        
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
mtxFn <- args[1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
pdfFn <- args[2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

mtx <- read.table(mtxFn, col.names=c("x", "y", "level"))                                                                                                                                                                                      
mtx$level[(mtx$level == 1)] <- NA                                                                                                                                                                                                             

library(lattice)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
trellis.device(dev=pdf, file=pdfFn)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
colors <- colorRampPalette(c('red', 'white'))(256)                                                                                                                                                                                            
fig <- levelplot(level~x*y,                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                 data=mtx,                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                 col.regions=colors,                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                 xlab="",                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                 ylab="",                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                 aspect="iso",                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                 scales=list(                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                   x=list(rot=90)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                   ),                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                 panel=function(...) {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                   arg <- list(...)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                   panel.levelplot(...)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                   panel.text(mtx$x, mtx$y, round(mtx$level*100,0), cex=0.5)                                                                                                                                                                  
                 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                 )                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
print(fig)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
graphics.off();
```

This works fine. I get the following figure:

[image: levelplot]

However, instead of having cells labeled `NA`, I would like to leave them as `1.00` values, but color all cells between 10 (a level of `0.10`) and 79 (a level of `0.79`) with `colors`. Anything greater than 79 gets colored with the same color as what is applied to a cell with the approx. level of 79. Or, preferably, said cells would be colored black, with no text inside them at all.

Is there a way to accomplish this with `levelplot` and lattice?

---

**FINAL EDIT**

This doesn't give much of a gradient in colors, but I'm close enough that I'll award the bounty, and perhaps look into `ggplot2` as an alternative. Thanks for all your hard work on this.

Here is the final edit of my script:

```
#! /foo/bar/bin/Rscript --vanilla
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
dfFn <- args[1]
pdfFn <- args[2]

df <- read.table(dfFn, 
                 col.names=c("x", "y", "level"), 
                 stringsAsFactors=TRUE, 
                 colClasses=c("factor", "factor", "numeric"))
df$level <- round(df$level*100, 0)

# reorder cell type row-factors (in reverse of given order)
df$y <- factor(df$y, levels=unique(df$y[length(df$y):1]))

lowestValue <- min(df$level)
secondHighestValue <- unique(sort(df$level, decreasing=TRUE))[2]

n <- 10
col.seq <- seq(lowestValue, secondHighestValue, length.out=n)
brks <- c(0, col.seq, Inf)
cuts <- cut(df$level, breaks = brks)
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(length(levels(cuts))-1)
colors <- c(colors, "black")

cls <- rep(colors, times = table(cuts))

library(lattice)
trellis.device(dev=pdf, file=pdfFn)
fig <- levelplot(cuts~x*y,
                 data = df,
                 cuts = n,
                 col.regions=cls,
                 xlab="",
                 ylab="",
                 aspect="iso",
                 scales=list(
                   x=list(rot=90)
                   ),
                 panel=function(...) {
                   arg <- list(...)
                   panel.levelplot(...)
                   panel.text(df$x, df$y, df$level, cex=0.5)
                 },
                 colorkey=list(col=colorRampPalette(c("white", "red"))(length(col.seq)), at=col.seq)
                 )
print(fig)
graphics.off()
```

Here is the `levelplot` that this script makes:

[image: vFinal]

If I increase `n` above `15`, the cell coloring breaks once again, returning to a diagonal of bright red, instead of black (as shown).

Comment: I would construct bins using `cut(x, breaks = c(0, 1, seq(10, 79, 1), 80, Inf))` and assign an appropriate color to each using your `colorRampPalette`. Through `seq`, you can always make a desirable number of levels. As for your NA-s, leave out your 5th statement.

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data online (dropbox or somesuch)?

Comment: Thanks very much -- please see: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31495717/stackoverflow.overlaps.list.txt

Comment: Ok, another revision. I hope this time you like what you see. Fingers crossed. :)

Comment: Hey Alex, did the Dropbox file change? I'm testing out some ggplot2 code and I see different values (hence graph)?

Comment: No, it's the same file, as far as I know. I haven't touched it since I uploaded it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This is revision #3*

Here we go (again). :)

This is weird, if I set n to anything below 15, things seem to work?

[image]

```
df <- read.table("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31495717/stackoverflow.overlaps.list.txt",
        sep = "\t", header = FALSE)
names(df) <- c("x", "y", "level")
df$level <- round(df$level*100, 0)

n <- 10
col.seq <- seq(10, 80, length.out = n)
brks <- c(0, seq(10, 80, length.out = n), 100)
cuts <- cut(df$level, breaks = brks)
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white"))(length(levels(cuts))-1)
colors <- c(colors, "black")

cls <- rep(colors, times = table(cuts))

print(levelplot(cuts~x*y,
                data = df,
                cuts = n,
                col.regions=cls,
                xlab="",
                ylab="",
                aspect="iso",
                scales=list(
                        x=list(rot=90)
                ),
                panel=function(...) {
                    arg <- list(...)
                    panel.levelplot(...)
                    panel.text(df$x, df$y, df$level, cex=0.5)
                },
                colorkey = list(col = colors, at = brks)
        ))
```

Comment: I apologize, but I do not understand this answer.

Comment: This is the code you should run (with minor changes to make it fit your bill) before calling levelplot. I suggest you run R interactively to round the edges and then go into "production mode" through a bash script.

Comment: I do not know how to fit your code into what I have already written, sorry. Where does `kats` get used, why is it called that, etc.?

Comment: Where does `cls` come from, etc.? It is unclear how this answer relates to my particular situation.

Comment: Sorry, cls was from my previous ("offline") code, then I adapted it for your code. `cls` is actually `kats`. I've mended my answer. You put this code before your `colors` variable (it actually replaces your `colors` variable).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, this did not work. I have posted updated code and the image result to the question. If you have any other thoughts, I'd appreciate your advice.

Comment: Thanks again for updated code. Your example works for making your example, but does not work with my data. Ultimately, I don't know what is different between your data frame and mine. Other than data values, the structure is the same: three columns: two factors and a third numeric column. There must be something wrong with the format of my sample data, but it doesn't appear to be any different from your sample data. R is frustrating!

Comment: I think there should be a diagonal line of black cells, not random values throughout the figure. I'll try your code on my side, removing the line of code where you put in `runif` data into the level column.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are using my data. Your randomly-sampled data (obtained via `runif`) works with your cuts and coloring. My dataset does not work with your cuts and coloring. If I use `class`, `length` and `min` and `max` to determine the type, size and range of the random and real datasets, only the range differs. In theory, the `runif` function should make data equivalent to mine, i.e. within [0,1] so it's not clear why the `cuts` variable bins my real data incorrectly, but it does bin your random `runif` data correctly.

Comment: @AlexReynolds Ah, copy/paste. I've edited my answer. Interesting behavior if I modify `n`.