# Plotting sorted heatmap keeping (x,y) value colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I've been working with python, pandas and seaborn to get a heatmap with different colormaps/columns. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25154056/plotting-of-2d-data-heatmap-with-different-colormaps/25155255#25155255) question I did the following:

*Sample Dataframe* (sample.csv):

```
X,a,b,c
A,0.5,0.7,0.4
B,0.9,0.3,0.8
C,0.3,0.4,0.7
```

*Plot Heatmap with Seaborn*

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
# Set new Backend to Use Seaborn
# mpl.use('Agg')
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import colorsys

# Working example data:
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.5,0.7,0.4],[.9,.3,.8],[.3,.4,.7]],['A','B','C'])    

# Get Color List
N = 3
COL = [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(x*1.0/N, 0.7, 0.5) for x in range(N)]

with sns.axes_style('white'):

    for i, name in enumerate(df.columns):

        # Create cmap
        colors = COL[i]
        cmap = sns.light_palette(colors, input='rgb', reverse=False, as_cmap=True)

        sns.heatmap(df.mask(df.isin(df[name])!=1),
                    cbar=False,
                    square=True,
                    annot=False,
                    cmap=cmap,
                    linewidths=0.1)
plt.show()
```

This produce a heatmap with different colormaps / column (the values are only there to clarify the problem):

[image]

Now I would like to produce the same plot using the sorted dataframe like:

```
X,col1,col2,col3
A,0.7,0.5,0.4
B,0.9,0.8,0.3
C,0.7,0.4,0.3
```

Trying to keep the original color of the pair (index,column), like the following expected draft output (values are indicative, what I would need are only the colors):

[image]

EDIT:

Fixed some typos, now df is the dataframe representing the working matrix.

Comment: I am not sure I understood the problem here, I left a tentative answer, but I would edit this question to make more clear where you are and what precise issue you are facing

Comment: Provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with what you have done so far so that I can understand what is actually your problem

Comment: I thought that my second edit would have helped. The working example is still there, I cannot reproduce an output since it is my problem.

Comment: The working example is not there because **it is not working**. You can build the dataframes you gave as example and plot the heatmap with those fictional values.

Comment: I was referring to the main code example that reproduce the graphical output. The second edit is just pseudocode that would have helped in understanding my needs. If I was able to write a working example I would not have asked the question.

Comment: I can understand what you need to do now, still it would be nice to have some code to copy/paste to reproduce the first heatmap and work from there. The way it is now if someone wants to help has to do everything by themselves. So, even though it is understandable now, please provide a minimal working example

Comment: Not sure if you want to deviate but this blog post shows how to plot a heatmap without using Seaborn: http://nipunbatra.github.io/2014/07/dtw/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could once iterate over the array and get the colours corresponding to each value and store them in an NxMx3 (image) array. Then sort the array and the image in the same manner e.g. get the sort indices from the original array and apply them to the image array. Then you can display the image with `plt.imshow`
You then can add with matplotlib labels, ticks, etc.

This could look like that:
You should first create an NxMx3 array to store the colors.

`im = np.zeros((df.shape[0], df.shape[1], 3))`

You then can iterate over every column and scale your value from 0 to 255, e.g.

`color_index = (value-min(column))/(max(column)-min(column)*255`

then you can use

`color = cmap(color_index)`

`im[col_index, row_index, :] = color`

When you have iterated over every column, you have all the colors stored in `im`

The resulting code would be:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
# Set new Backend to Use Seaborn
# mpl.use('Agg')
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import colorsys
import numpy as np

# Working example data:
df = pd.DataFrame([[0.5,0.7,0.4],[.9,.3,.8],[.3,.4,.7]],['A','B','C'])    

# Get Color List
N = 3
COL = [colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(x*1.0/N, 0.7, 0.5) for x in range(N)]

im = np.zeros((df.shape[0], df.shape[1], 4))

with sns.axes_style('white'):

    for i, name in enumerate(df.columns):

        # Create cmap
        colors = COL[i]
        cmap = sns.light_palette(colors, input='rgb', reverse=False, as_cmap=True)
        values = np.array(df[name])
        color_indices = (values-np.min(values))/(np.max(values)-np.min(values))
        im[:,i,:] = cmap(color_indices)

im2 = im.copy()
for i, name in enumerate(df.T.columns):
    values = np.array(df.T[name])
    print(values)
    sorting = np.argsort(values)
    print("sorting", sorting)
    im2[i, ::-1, :] = im[i, sorting, :]
plt.imshow(im2, interpolation="nearest")
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that, but how can I have access to the colors for each position? That would be very useful.

Comment: Looks promising, but do you mind providing a complete example and output? You're close to win the bounty! :-)

Answer (score 1):

With [seaborn heatmap](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) you just need to provide the different color maps and, independently of the order, set `vmin` and `vmax`. Actually,

> vmin, vmax : floats, optional
>
> > Values to anchor the colormap, otherwise they are inferred from the data and other keyword arguments.

Which means that you should not need to specify the min/max values unless you want them outside of your data points.