# Conditionally color pandas dataframe by column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working on a jupyter notebook right now and I am looking for a way to conditionally color each cell in a pandas dataframe according to its relative value within the column (or alternatively row).

**The final output should be a pandas dataframe.**
Conceptually it would be like creating a heatmap where the shading is defined independently for each column and is based on the max and min of the column itself.

I have had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25155255/3284713) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44020508/3284713) but in both they create actual plot as output instead of coloring the dataframe cells.

Comment: Do you mean coloring the output in the console?

Comment: right, I am sorry. I am working on a jupyter notebook right now =) I'll update the question

Comment: How do you display your dataframe? Have you looked at this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html ?

Comment: Thanks @KarlAnka, didn't know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `style` method. The output looks like a dataframe, but is not.
If you want each column to have a color gradient corresponding to the values of the column:

```
df.style.background_gradient()
```

To apply the style row-wise, use the additional parameter `axis=1`.

Answer (score 6):

You can find more options here: [Pandas DataFrame Styling: Builtin Styles](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Builtin-styles)

```py
import seaborn as sns
cm = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)

df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm, axis=0) # explicitly applying column-wise
```

The output will look like:
[image]